# The proper relationship between a text cursor and a QTextEdit widget?

Tags: python, qt, oop, pyside, qtextedit

I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding the proper relationship between a text cursor and a QTextEdit widget in Qt. Are they best viewed as temporary constructs created and used within particular methods? Right now, I create cursors in methods using `cursor = self.textCursor()`. I use the cursor programmatically and then assign the results to the widget using `self.setTextCursor(cursor)`. Sometimes though I want to know whether there is currently a selection and `cursor` fails as an undefined variable. Of course, I could use `cursor = self.textCursor()` beforehand. But, I wonder if all QTextEdit widgets are supposed to have a permanent cursor such as `self.cursor =  QtextCursor()` which exists between method calls as part of the object? As someone new to Python, Object-oriented programming, and Qt, this is part of a larger question of when to create object properties using `self` and when to create local variables instead. So far, I've tended to create object properties whenever I feel the temptation to create global variables. So, my question is how are text cursors best defined and does this follow an overall philosophy to programming with Qt and Python?

Comment: The [textCursor()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#textCursor) method returns a `const` object that is a copy of the current cursor. It makes no sense to keep it around, since it is not dynamically updated. I suggest you read [The QTextCursor Interface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-cursor.html) article in the Qt Docs, which is part of the [Rich Text Processing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext.html) reference.

Comment: I'll read those materials more carefully. I understand that `textCursor()` is static, but thought it would be possible to continually update it so a variable called `self.cursor` is always current. But, that is unnecessary because the `QTextEdit` class handles basic editing without the programmer needing to do anything.

Comment: Well, you can update it, like so: `self.cursor = self.textCursor()`. But what would be the point?

Comment: The more I read about cursors, the more I agree with you. There is no point in updating self.cursor. In Qt, cursors are temporary constructs created to fulfill an immediate need. Thank you for teaching me that.